# how to reverse scale a scaled numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array, example:

```
signal =array([[    0,     0,     0,  3485,  3480,  3474],
               [    0,     0,     0,  5644,  5642,  5655],
               [    0,     0,     0,  6622,  6541,  6623],
               [ 4555,  4656, 11232, 11265, 11564, 11553],
               [ 3450,  3455,  3536,  3510,  3564,  3375]])
```

I used the scaling    `((signal) / np.max(signal)*255).astype(np.uint8)`
It's became

```
f = array([[  0,   0,   0,  76,  76,  76],
           [  0,   0,   0, 124, 124, 124],
           [  0,   0,   0, 146, 144, 146],
           [100, 102, 247, 248, 255, 254],
           [ 76,  76,  77,  77,  78,  74]], dtype=uint8)
```

so, now I want to generate the `signal` array from the `f` array.
I tried the reverse scale like,
`(f * np.max(signal)/255).astype(np.uint32)`
but It's giving me

```
array([[  0,   0,   0, 105, 105, 105],
       [  0,   0,   0, 226, 226, 226],
       [  0,   0,   0, 195, 105, 195],
       [165, 256, 150, 195, 255, 210],
       [105, 105, 150, 150, 196,  14]])
```

which is not appropriate.
so what should I do to reverse the scaling of the array to get the previous original input data?

Comment: With `f.astype(np.uint32) * np.max(signal) // 255` you get the best possible reconstruction after quantization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are multiplying an array with dtype `uint8` with maximum value of signal. This data type can't hold an integer that large so overflow happens and the numbers are wrapped to the range of 0->255. you have to convert it to `uint32` first and then scale:

```
signal = f.astype(np.uint32) * np.max(signal)/255
```

After this, the output will still be a little different than original and that is because of converting floating point results to `uint8` which will cause your numbers to lose their fraction.